# How to change between speakers and USB headset using a script on Ubuntu?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, audio, alsa

I am trying to write a script to change between speakers and headset. I want to be able to change the output and the input with a shortcut.

I used these commands to see my audio devices :

```
$ pacmd list-sinks | grep alsa_output 

name: <alsa_output.usb-Logitech_Logitech_USB_Headset-00.analog-stereo>
name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>

$ pacmd list-sources | grep alsa_input

name: <alsa_input.usb-Logitech_Logitech_USB_Headset-00.analog-mono>
name: <alsa_input.usb-093a_262c-01.analog-mono>
name: <alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
```

And wrote this script so I can change the default audio device.

```
#! /bin/bash

  pacmd set-default-sink alsa_output.usb-Logitech_Logitech_USB_Headset-00.analog-stereo
  pacmd set-default-source alsa_input.usb-Logitech_Logitech_USB_Headset-00.analog-mono

exit 0
```

When I run this with the command

```
 sudo ./usb-speakers.sh
```

I get this messages :

> No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
>   Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
>   No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.

I found several questions with similar problems but I can't make anything work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this script (I can't remember where ) which solve all my problems

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i sinks=(`pacmd list-sinks | sed -n -e 's/\**[[:space:]]index:[[:space:]]\([[:digit:]]\)/\1/p'`)
declare -i sinks_count=${#sinks[*]}
declare -i active_sink_index=`pacmd list-sinks | sed -n -e 's/\*[[:space:]]index:[[:space:]]\([[:digit:]]\)/\1/p'`
declare -i next_sink_index=${sinks[0]}

#find the next sink (not always the next index number)
declare -i ord=0
while [ $ord -lt $sinks_count ];
do
echo ${sinks[$ord]}
if [ ${sinks[$ord]} -gt $active_sink_index ] ; then
    next_sink_index=${sinks[$ord]}
    break
fi
let ord++
done

#change the default sink
pacmd "set-default-sink ${next_sink_index}"

#move all inputs to the new sink
for app in $(pacmd list-sink-inputs | sed -n -e 's/index:[[:space:]]\([[:digit:]]\)/\1/p');
do
pacmd "move-sink-input $app $next_sink_index"
done

#display notification
declare -i ndx=0
pacmd list-sinks | sed -n -e 's/device.description[[:space:]]=[[:space:]]"\(.*\)"/\1/p' | while read line;
do
if [ $(( $ord % $sinks_count )) -eq $ndx ] ; then
    notify-send -i notification-audio-volume-high --hint=string:x-canonical-private-synchronous: "Sound output switched to" "$line"
    exit
fi
let ndx++
done;
```

just copy and paste it in an empty document and save it as 
`audio-device-swithcer.sh`

then save it to your `usr/local/bin` directory

If you want to add a shortcut go to `Keyboard & Shortcuts` and add a new shortcut.
As a command just put your `audio-device-switcher.sh` file

That's all guys that worked perfectly for me .
And thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/mk-fg/pulseaudio-mixer-cli/blob/master/README.md says:

> Kinda like alsamixer, focused not on sink volume levels (which can actually be controlled via alsamixer, with alsa-pulse plugin), but rather on volume of individual streams, so you can turn down the music to hear the stuff from games, mumble, skype or browser.
>
> In addition to interactive UI, script allows to match and configure sink/stream parameters via config file, so that when specific sink or stream appears, e.g. its volume can be capped, port changed, UI title adjusted, be hidden in UI, stuff like that.

Comment: Hi, and thank you for your answer I tried to install this plugin but I get the following error:
`File "./pa-mixer-mk3.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pulsectl import Pulse, PulseLoopStop, PulseDisconnected, PulseIndexError
ImportError: No module named 'pulsectl'`

And I installed `pulsectl` using this commands :

 `apt-get install python-pip
 pip install pulsectl`

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea why it didn't work. I'll try to replicate when I have an Ubuntu box in front of me instead of a phone.